# A question about chassis mount SMPS mounting

Tags: diy, power-supply

I have couple of [chassis-mount 75 W, 15 V DC Mean Well switching power supplies](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/switching-power-supplies/1065837) (the PDF datasheet is [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/f3fc/0900766b814e41f9.pdf)) and I need to mount them as in a shelf of a 19" rack frame.

I have no prior experience how it is done in practice, but I was thinking to use a DIN rail adapter and find a rack shelf which I can mount these supplies onto.

But I wonder if someone has any expertise with it? How to safely fix such supplies on a plate or a rack shelf?

Note:  This questioned was first asked by me in electrical engineering and engineering se. But were closed because of out of topic. Then based on a suggestion comment I asked at diy.se but they also closed the question.

As a last resort desperately I'm asking here.

Comment: Looks like several holes to bolt to a rack shelf, or use some L-brackets and use the threaded holes on the sides. Hardware options are likely available in a DIY store near you.

Comment: It might be OT here too, but we're going to allow it. :-)

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a drawing of the mounting holes, etc. to your question. You might get better answers, too.

Comment: @JonCuster Or a small 19" rack blank. Good suggestions, you should put that in an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "19" rack blank". What is a "blank"?

Comment: A blank is simply a 19" wide piece of metal with slots for mounting screws at each end, (preferably) without any pre-drilled holes (for looks, if that is of concern to you). A 1U height blank *might* work instead of a 2U slot blank suggested by [Gil](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/21641/8717). There is no shelf here, it's just a thin vertical piece of metal 19" wide.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it several times with larger units. I get a 2U slot blank and make two brackets by bending some 1/8" thick by 1/2" wide metal into L brackets. Probably about 5" x 1 1/2" (just a bit smaller than 2U) and put two holes in each for mounting. I then mount the power supply on the bracketts (holes drilled first). If you have more then 1 it can be mounted beside the existing one, or go to a widder blank plate and mount them horizontally.

Without knowing how many you are mounting I gave an idea of both horizontal and vertical mounting. Looking at the picture it appears they have screw holes on the side for mounting, use them.  You could mount them directly to the blank plate but I would not recommend that.

[image]

Comment: What is a "blank"?

Comment: @GNZ See [my comment here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/21640/a-question-about-chassis-mount-smps-mounting#comment38173_21640).

Comment: Does he really need two brackets? I envision mounting the unit horizontally, directly to the blank with 2 screws (on top).

Comment: He needs two attachment points, doesn't matter if they are the panel or a bracket or a combination. 1 mounting point will allow it to spin on the mounting point if the screw comes loose.

Comment: @Gil Can you provide a photo or sketch of what you suggest?

Comment: I currently do not access to that facility. Think of it as you have a box you want to support. You can bolt it to the wall (blank plate) or you can use a pair of shelf supports (brackets). Why 2? balance that box on one bracket or mount with one screw.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the group.

> I was thinking to use a DIN rail adapter and find a rack shelf which I can mount these supplies onto.

These are not DIN rail mounted devices. There are various threaded holes and a slot shown on the drawings for fastening to a chassis.

> How to safely fix such supplies on a plate or a rack shelf?

You can't. Note that there are accessible (if recessed) AC connections for these power supplies. They are intended to be mounted inside an enclosure for safety, not fixed to an open shelf (see note 8 at the bottom of page 2 of your linked datasheet).

They are only 30 mm high so they should fit into an enclosed 1U (1¾"/44 mm) rack-mount chassis. It may be preferable for the chassis to have ventilation louvres/fan. There will be plenty of space left in the chassis for any other bits of random circuitry that need a home. Here's an example of a [1U enclosed chassis](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/subracks/2457828).